# Docx4j in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, docx4j

Hello I'm trying to implement this library in AWS lambda.
But I got stuck in

`wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();`

And the lambda would timeout.

I can execute the function in my local environment.

Anyone can help me here?

I'm Using Java JDK 8 for my local environment.

The lambda function has execution basic role and s3 full permission with 1024MB of memory and 10 seconds of execution limit. The function is not in any VPC.

EDIT:
Here's my full log after adding log4j

```
`START RequestId: ab3cc460-ddfd-11e7-bb93-43bcee7d169c Version: $LATEST
Dec 10, 2017 10:58:42 PM pp.generator.docx.RequestFunctionHandler 
handleRequest
INFO: Handling request
Dec 10, 2017 10:58:43 PM pp.generator.docx.RequestFunctionHandler 
handleRequest
INFO: Creating Word processingMLPackage
DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 70 - Attempting to load: docx4j.properties
0 [main] DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils  - Attempting to load: docx4j.properties
DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 87 - Trying Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
10 [main] DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils  - Trying Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
WARN org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 96 - Couldn't get resource: docx4j.properties
11 [main] WARN org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils  - Couldn't get resource: docx4j.properties
WARN org.docx4j.Docx4jProperties .init line 22 - Couldn't find/read docx4j.properties; docx4j.properties not found via classloader.
12 [main] WARN org.docx4j.Docx4jProperties  - Couldn't find/read docx4j.properties; docx4j.properties not found via classloader.
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 86 - java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
76 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context  - java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 87 - java.version=1.8.0_141
76 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context  - java.version=1.8.0_141
DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 70 - Attempting to load: org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties
172 [main] DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils  - Attempting to load: org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties
DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 87 - Trying Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
172 [main] DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils  - Trying Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 94 - Not using MOXy, since no resource: org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties
189 [main] DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils  - Not using MOXy, since no resource: org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils .getPrefixMapper line 75 - 
Using NamespacePrefixMapperSunInternal, which is suitable for Java 6
432 [main] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils  - Using NamespacePrefixMapperSunInternal, which is suitable for Java 6
END RequestId: ab3cc460-ddfd-11e7-bb93-43bcee7d169c
REPORT RequestId: ab3cc460-ddfd-11e7-bb93-43bcee7d169c  Duration: 10003.62 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 127 MB 
2017-12-10T22:58:52.783Z ab3cc460-ddfd-11e7-bb93-43bcee7d169c Task timed out after 10.00 seconds`
```

Comment: What does the log say?  One time JAXB context init should take less than 10 sec (depending on the hardware)

Comment: I only got this in the cloudwatch logs
`INFO: Creating Word processingMLPackage`,

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils).`,

`log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`

The INFO one is my custom logger before the .createPackage() method.

I wrapped the statement in try catch block but it doesn't throws any error.

Is there any preconfiguration of the lambda function that I should be aware of? I executed the code in my local computer and it works fine.

Comment: Add https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/_resources/log4j.xml to your class path

Comment: But I guess you need to increase the "10 seconds of execution limit".

Comment: First step would be to get lambda to log that this is what is happening.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to edit the code in the weekend. I added the logs and it seems to have stopped in `INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils  - Using NamespacePrefixMapperSunInternal, which is suitable for Java 6` and if I try to run it in my local environment, `Not using MOXy; using com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl` is the next log.

Comment: Oh.. You're right! modifying the timeout to 30 sec did it! it took 16.8sec in the first run. Do you know why does it took so long? The next request only took 500ms though. And I don't think it's because of the cold start because AWS billed 16.8 sec in that request. Anyway, thanks a lot! If you answer this question, I'll mark the answer as correct! Thanks again!

Comment: Nowadays you can avoid the Java/JAXB startup time by creating a substrate native image using graal, then running that on lambda as a custom runtime.